# Lotus Notes mailboxes database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I was given a task, a list of 3k+ mailboxes DBs on it. They want me to review the list if it can be deleted and will not affect any DBs/Apps we're supporting(about 20). Any advice on how to do this w/o going through all the 3k+ DBs?

Like if I check this one DB/App, I can see if there are any mailboxes DBs connected to it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily list databases in the mail subdirectory, but that's hardly definitive.  (A mail database can be in any subdirectory.)  You can also create a list of databases that use the Mail template.  That's hardly definitive either (any database can use the Mail template.)  You can go through the Names.nsf (and any secondary address books) and look at the databases listed  in the various Person documents, but that's about it.

Further, there's no concept of "connected".  The code in one database can try to open another, but chances are that "connection" is fleeting and during runtime.  And the code can be @Formula, LotusScript, Java, or even a Web service.

So as I see it, you have two options, 1) Comb through all the design synopses of all the databases and find all of them that reference the mail databases, or 2) Perform the "Scream" test.  Make the mail unavailable and see who screams.

Comment: Hi duston, thank you for you response. I forgot to mention that we dont use the mail in lotus notes anymore, we just want to check if any of our db are associated to mailboxes exist. How do I make the mail unavailable? Remove the user's access via ACL in each mailboxes db? Thanks.

Comment: The only way I see it being done is alternative 1) above. You have to look at the code.

Comment: "il in lotus notes anymore, we just want to check if any of our db are associated to mailboxes exist. How do I make the mail unavailable" Yes, that's what I had in mind, set access to "No Access" for everyone except for maybe one person who can set it back if needed.

Comment: To be clear "we dont use the mail in lotus notes anymore": does not mean that there aren't applications that are still sending or receivng mail on you Domino servers.  Just shutting out user access will not stop that.  At the very least, you should be looking at the Mail-In Database documents in the Domino Directory.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thank you for your input. I looked into the Mail-in Databases and Resources in the Domino Directories. I only found 200+ databases, which is very few compare to what I was given. Is is safe to say that these databases only are currently in use and give this list to the client and say these are the databases that should not be deleted?Thanks.